# How does Idra command his initial drones to mine individual mineral clusters?

Tags: starcraft-2

See his VOD cast - http://www.justin.tv/eg_idra/b/278424082

I'm noticing he's executing some command while having all drones selected.

Comment: I've never lost a game and thought, if only I split better.
see http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=129010

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, I looked as the link and here is what I saw:

1. Idra selects all drones (by boxing)
2. Idra sends drones past mineral line, then to a specific patch
3. Idra selects 3 drones
4. Idra sends those drones to a second patch
5. Idra selects 2 drones
6. Idra sends them to a third patch

Let's see it in slow mo:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. [image]
6. [image]

Its in 2 seconds he has split his drones in groups of 2.  Its beautiful, like watching ballet

Comment: Thanks for the visuals.  Any ideas why he clicks behind the mineral line before selecting a mineral cluster?

Comment: Nevermind I got it.  It's to spread the drones out, as opposed to stacking them.

Comment: @Teiva actually I think it was just a mis-click as he clicks on the mineral patch right after

Answer (score 3):

Another way to split drones is to hit the hotkey to select a single idle drone, and click a mineral patch. Do this 6 times really fast, and each drone goes right to its own mineral patch. Something like,

- F1
- Right-click 1st mineral patch
- F1
- Right-click 2nd mineral patch
- F1
- Right-click 3rd mineral patch
- F1
- Right-click 4th mineral patch
- F1
- Right-click 5th mineral patch
- F1
- Right-click 6th mineral patch

This is much easier than selecting the individual drone and mineral patch, but it's still to hard for me to do effectively.

But honestly, as @Aardvark says, the initial split is not that important. This amount of analysis / practice would be better spent on something like hydra micro or macro.

So while I have seen this done in game, it's something I don't care to perfect.

- Edit: I don't know what the hot key is to select a single idle worker... I think it's F1 for me (i'm on lefty grid).

Comment: `F1` is indeed the default keystroke to select an idle worker.

Comment: You can just hold F1.

Comment: @recursive: you just made my day; that is brilliant. Seems I can do this and earn my first 80 mins 1 second faster. Not going to win me the game, but I like meticulous things like this as a way to keep sharp.

Answer (score 2):

You may be witnessing legendary micro but it is probably just a lag spike (where he is in the game and can select each unit individually).  Most players do a 3/3 split to two sets of minerals.

To do this hold CTRL during the loading screen and press F1 when you enter the game (select all + idle workers) right click on one mineral node then box 3 drones (drag and select) and have them go to another set of minerals.

Keep in mind though that in the scheme of a game of starcraft your initial worker micro is pretty small potatoes compared to your decisions later in the game (forgetting to build workers, supply blocking etc)

Comment: Lag spikes are viewable in a VOD.  What they see is what you see.  Idra has managed to pull this opening move off in every VOD I've seen.  The above VOD has at least 4 games in it.

Comment: It's a valid point that this inquiry has a minimal effect on the overall macro play, but it bothers me not knowing how.  I was just curious if anyone knew the answer.